# How to use aws kms encrypt when "plaintext" starts with dash (-)

Tags: bash, aws

I want to encrypt a client secret that starts with a dash, but if I do something like:

```
aws kms encrypt --region us-east-1 --key-id xxxyyzz --output text --query CiphertextBlob --plaintext -blahblah-
```

The result is:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --plaintext: expected one argument
```

Tried escaping like:

```
aws kms encrypt --region us-east-1 --key-id xxxyyzz --output text --query CiphertextBlob --plaintext \-blahblah-
```

But got the same error. My searches so far only gave application specific answers (e.g. `sed`). What's the elusive trick I'm missing?

Comment: did you try with single quotes? `'-blahblah-'`

Comment: I did, same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, doing `aws kms encrypt help` gave me the solution:

```bsh
$ aws kms encrypt --region us-east-1 --key-id vvvvvvvv --output text --query CiphertextBlob --plaintext fileb://clientsecret.txt
```

Where *clientsecret.txt* holds the string that contains dashes, without a new line character.

Comment: Your OS is Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu).